# How to explain this basic summation rule: $\sum_{i = 1}^n c = n\cdot c$, where $c$ is a constant?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, soft-question, riemann-sum

The parallel rule for definite integrals , namely,

$$\int_a^b c = c(b - a)$$ where $c$ s a constant, is rather intuitive, due to the fact that this number is computed in a way similar to the area of a rectangle. But it is difficult to make sense of a sum involving a variable $i$ that is not a term of this sum, the only term being the constant $c$ (but I may miss something here).

Is the rule true by definition so to say, or can it be explained by another more basic rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a consequence of the distributive property. Note that

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n c &= \underbrace{c+c+\ldots+c}_{n\text{ times}} \\
&= \underbrace{1\cdot c+1\cdot c+\ldots+1\cdot c}_{n\text{ times}} \\
&= \left(\underbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}_{n\text{ times}}\right)\cdot c \\
&= n\cdot c
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Could  the first line be grounded in the fact that c = c+ 0.i ? I would like an explanation that derives formally the result from the definition of a sum involving the variable i. Thanks:)

Comment: A way to justify the first line is like this: if we have a finite sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ is defined to be the sum of the members of that sequence. In other words, by definition, $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n$. Here we have a sequence where $a_i=c$ for each integer $i$ with $1\le i\le n$. Hence $\sum_{i=1}^n c=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n=\underbrace{c+c+\ldots+c}_{n\text{ times}}$

Comment: this is clear, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for posting the question!

Answer (score 1):

It's the same. $c=c\cdot 1$, the area of a rectangle of height $c$ and width one. The sum says add up $n$ of 'em.